# Loop through table rows and call stored procedure on every row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently facing the issue that i have to loop through all rows of a given table, process the value of a column in that row and save the processed result with some more data from that row into a new table.

My problem is that i am not that firm with that kind of sql statements. Can anyone give me some tipps or buzzwords to work with?

Maybe some pseudocode (c#) will help you understand my problem

```
foreach(var row in tableRows)  {
 var processedValue = ProcessColumn(row.columnToBeProcessed)  
 InsertIntoResultTable(row.column1, row.column2, processedValue
}
```

So what i want to achieve is a new table with the processedvalue for each row and some original data from that row

Comment: Relational databases are optimized to be used in a set manner, that is multiple rows at the same time. You should avoid doing "1 by 1" loops as the performace will drastically decrease. What you need in this case is a simple `INSERT INTO` with your transformations as expressions in the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: Ok, thats one good thing to know :) coming from the c# world where this task would be easy i have a big problem creating a theoretical solution to my problem. Can u give a small example for that expression in the insert into statment. And can i use custom functions for that transformation?

Comment: Post your source table's data as example and the transformation you need to do before inserting on the target table and we can make an insert statement for you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer i will do that when i really don`t come to any solution. I will try that on my own with the hints you provided me, because thats how i learn the most :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to AVOID row-by-row statements in sql (search for RBAR), and do a set operation instead. Try something like:

```
Insert Into ResultTable (
    column1, 
    column2, 
    processedValue)
select 
    ot.column1, 
    ot.column2, 
    yourFunction(ot.column3) AS ProcessedValue
from 
    originalTable ot
```

Comment: Thanks for the RBAR hint, helps me to understand more how sql works

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a C# `foreach` in SQL Server would be a [`CURSOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This allows you to perform per-row operations on a set of data. Use cursors sparingly, however. They should be avoided wherever possible, as they do not perform well compared to set-based operations you would normally perform in a SQL query.

Another alternative, if possible, is to use User-defined Functions in conjunction with a [`CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply), like so:

```
SELECT TableRows.Column1, TableRows.Column2, func.ProcessedValue
FROM TableRows
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_DataProcessingFunction(TableRows.ColumnToBeProcessed) AS func;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logic through your pseudocode, there is no loop necessarily, you can use scalar function, and select the rows as usual

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ProcessColumn (@Column)
RETURN NUMERIC
BEGIN
     --Your process here,
     --this is some example
    DECLARE @var numeric
    SET @var = @column + 1
    RETURN @var
END
```

And then apply it into SELECT STATEMENT

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Column1, Column2, ProcessedColumn)

SELECT Column1, Column2, 
 --this is your function, with column of the table
 -- as parameter to be processed
     dbo.ProcessColumn(Column3)
FROM TABLESOURCE
```